# Android arrayindexoutofbounds error

Tags: android, arrays

I have an app on the android market where users report back occasional errors ArrayIndexOutofBounds(force close). I have never experienced this error myself, so it is hard for me figure out the problem. I was hoping that a more gifted programmer could give it a look. It happens when some people view this file dialog.

```
public void fileDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Choose the song file");
    if (canWriteToFlash()) {

    ScrollView sview = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout holder = new LinearLayout(this);
    holder.setOrientation(1);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + File.separator + "Music" + File.separator;

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    int count = 0;
    // count files in directory
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            count++;

        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
    TextView empty1 = new TextView(this);
         empty1.setText("The folder sdcard/Music, is empty. You must add song files in order to attach music to lyrics.");
         empty1.setTextSize(18);
         empty1.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 8);
         holder.addView(empty1);
    }

    // turn files into string array
    String[] sfiles = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            sfiles[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        }
    }
    // Sort Array case insenstive
    Arrays.sort(sfiles, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    // create text
    TextView[] t1 = new TextView[(count)];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            t1[i] = new TextView(this);
            t1[i].setText(sfiles[i]);
            t1[i].setPadding(7, 8, 7, 8);
            t1[i].setTextSize(18);
            holder.addView(t1[i]);
        }
    }
    // Create Click
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        final TextView thetext = t1[i];
        thetext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                songname = (String) thetext.getText();
                songfile.setText(songname);
                d.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
    }

    sview.addView(holder);
    d.setContentView(sview);
        } else {
       TextView usbt = new TextView(this);
       usbt.setText("Cannot communicate with sdcard! Make sure that USB connected is not enabled. Or try unplugging your USB cord.");
       usbt.setPadding(7, 8, 7, 8);
           usbt.setTextSize(18);
       d.setContentView(usbt);
    }

    d.show();
}
```

Comment: print (listOfFiles.length),what output give?

Answer (score 0):

I dont like this:

```
if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            t1[i] = new TextView(this);
            t1[i].setText(sfiles[i]);
            t1[i].setPadding(7, 8, 7, 8);
            t1[i].setTextSize(18);
            holder.addView(t1[i]);
        }
```

You are assuming sFiles[i] has the same position as listOfFiles[i] but you ordered before, so maybe its not the same file?

Anyway, besides that, you are asking the same over and over again. (if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {) If you have the complete stacktrace, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your "TextView" as final. Storing a reference to an object in a final field will make your reference immutable. It isn't creating any problems ?